In recharts library in line chart the line moves up after some specific values in data
I am using Next.js and in that I am using recharts library. Everything is working well except one thing. When I feed the value more than a specific value (in my case every value under 10) the line in line chart shrinks and move up for no reason. Though the grid remains at the same place.
Here are the images for the better understanding.
The image if I pass values which are more than 10

And here is the image if I feed the value below 10 also

By Looking at the code the problem will be even more clear.
By the way, the api that I am using is https://api.mfapi.in/mf/122639
page.tsx
"use client";
import React from "react";
import { CartesianGrid, Line, LineChart, ResponsiveContainer, XAxis, YAxis } from "recharts";

const LineChartComponent = (data: {
  data: { date: string; nav: string }[];
}) => {
    console.log(data.data.length);
  return (
    <div className="mt-9">
    <LineChart width={1000} height={500} data={data.data.filter((data) => {
        //If i use below condition everthing works fine.
        if(Number(data.nav) > 10){
            return true
        }
        //but as soon as i replace above condition with this condition it gives the output as i have shown above.
        if(Number(data.nav) > 9){
            return true
        }
        return false
    }).reverse()}>
      <Line type={"monotone"} dataKey={"nav"} stroke="#8884d8" />
      <CartesianGrid stroke="#ccc"/>
      <XAxis dataKey={"date"}/>
      <YAxis />
    </LineChart>
    </div> 
  );
};

export default LineChartComponent;


Could be related to how sensitive the scale adjustments are when domain is "auto". See issue here https://github.com/recharts/recharts/issues/4020. You could set the domain yourself in your XAxis to prevent this domain={(dataMin, dataMax) => [dataMin, dataMax + 10]}. If you create a sandbox with a reproduction it would be easier to narrow it down
